# Appium connect with Virtual Machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine, appium, appium-android

Virtual Machine link is `vnc://0.0.0.0:5901`

How will I use this to establish a connection with appium emulator?

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(newURL("vnc://0.0.0.0:5901/wd/hub"),desiredCapabilities);
```

Comment: Trying to run appium with docker image installed in local. Android emulator is installed in VM and need to run test in VM emulator. Not sure how to get the URL. Incase of local using http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub

Comment: Actually, the URL in `AndroidDriver` is the address of Appium hub, not the Android Emulator. You have to install Appium hub on your VM, and start it with your emulator in order to run the test.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you share any reference/steps for the above installation? Which would be of greater help.

Comment: In Virtual Machine, is there any command to download Appium Desktop App.

Comment: In [Appium's Getting started](http://appium.io/docs/en/about-appium/getting-started/), `Appium can be installed in one of two ways: via NPM or by downloading Appium Desktop, which is a graphical, desktop-based way to launch the Appium server.`. After installing it, you can start appium using terminal: `appium`. Type `appium --help` for more parameter's details. For more detail about installing appium, check [this](https://confusedcoders.com/general-programming/mobile/how-to-install-appium-in-ubuntu) out

Comment: In my case, I only need to config the server's address and port, so the command will be: `appium --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723`

Comment: And 1 more thing, actually it's the most inportant thing: you have to config your VM so that it can work as a server. Your above URL is the remote control URL, not a server's address.